# fixed sized pushbuttons laid out in gridlayout with predefined number of rows/cols

Tags: c++, qt, grid-layout

I've got a - maybe little bit unusual - problem:

I have a QTabWidget. The application reads records from a datasource. The records contain (besides other information) a "pos-x" and "pos-y" field and the app shall for each record put a Pushbutton on the tab-page at a grid-position (x,y). These pushbuttons have a "fixed" size, choosen by the user, which is read via a Config-Object from an ini file. If this "button-grid" becomes too large for the tab-page's space, scrollbars shall appear.

First I thought this was very easy and straight-forward. Something like "put a QScrollArea on the tab-page, put a QGridLayout into this QScrollarea. That's it". But then I realized that it is anything but simple.

As far as I understand Qt's "layouting and parenting", it's just the other way round. (Please correct me if I'm wrong!). "Normally", the surrounding widget sizes the Layout-manager (for example a QGridLayout) it contains, and the Layout-manager then sizes the childs it contains.

But I **think**, I need the "opposite direction". I have buttons of a fixed size, need a grid of n-rows by m-columns, which leads to a resulting size of the whole grid-layout. And if the whole layout doesn't fit, the scrollarea shall activate it's scrollbars.

So I'm a bit lost in this mystery now, wondering how to "correctly" do this. Maybe someone can kick me into the right direction...??

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozhMa.png) what do you want to get? If so, try to set the widget on the scroll area, not layout. Put a push buttons on the widget.

Then, if you mean a pos-x and pos-y are absolute, you don't need to set any layout on the widget. Just create a child push buttons and set their geometry as you need:

```
// Suppose we read this info from a config file
int pbWidth = 150, pbHeight = 30;
// and this one from a datasource
QVector<QPoint> positions;
positions.push_back(QPoint(10, 10));
positions.push_back(QPoint(50, 50));
positions.push_back(QPoint(210, 30));

QTabWidget *tabWidget = new QTabWidget();
QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea();
QWidget *scrollAreaWidget = new QWidget();

// We put a container widget inside the scroll area
scrollArea->setWidget(scrollAreaWidget);
// then we add the scroll area as the tab
tabWidget->addTab(scrollArea, tr("Tab 1"));

// Now let's put some push buttons on the widget
for (QVector<QPoint>::ConstIterator i = positions.cbegin();
     i != positions.cend(); i++)
{
  QString text = tr("Button at %1x%2").arg(i->x()).arg(i->y());
  // We have to pass the parent to the constructor
  // to place pb on the widget 
  QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton(text, scrollAreaWidget);

  // Here we set position and size
  pushButton->setGeometry(i->x(), i->y(), pbWidth, pbHeight);
}

// We have no layout on the widget, so don't forget to adjust size
scrollAreaWidget->adjustSize();
```